# A problem in proving jacobian properties with tensor notation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

I have an exercise that wants me to prove that $J^{i'}_iJ^i_{j'}=\delta^{i'}_{j'}$ using the fact that $J^i_{i'}J^{i'}_j=\delta^{i}_{j}$. It is also stated that I have to multiply both sides of the equation with $J^j_{j'}$. I have been unable to prove this identity.

I have tried to use the fact that if $\delta^i_{j}=1 \Leftrightarrow i=j$. The equation then becomes $J^{i'}_iJ^i_{j'}J^i_{i'}=J^i_{j'} \Leftrightarrow J^{i'}_iJ^i_{j'}=\frac{J^i_{j'}}{J^i_{i'}}$, which is not what was needed to be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tip given is to multiply what we're assuming by $J_{j^\prime}^j$, not what we want to prove. (This "multiplication" is actually a contraction over $j$, but we'll discuss contraction again later.) Since$$J_{i^\prime}^iJ_j^{i^\prime}J_{j^\prime}^j=\delta_j^iJ_{j^\prime}^j=J_{j^\prime}^i=\delta_{j^\prime}^{i^\prime}J_{i^\prime}^i,$$ it follows by matching $J_{i^\prime}^i$ coefficients that $J_i^{i^\prime}J_{j^\prime}^i=\delta_{j^\prime}^{i^\prime}$. This is not as simple as dividing by $J_{i^\prime}^i$; that's a fundamental misunderstanding of the contraction of tensor indices. We don't have a single quantity throughout named $J_{i^\prime}^i$, which is overall multiplied by a single quantity as a coefficient; we have a sum of such products over all choices of $i^\prime$.

Comment: Oh I see because $i'$ is a repeated index it is a part of a sum and thats why $J^i_{i'}$ is not just a number. But now that we have two sums which both have the same index dividing is allowed, right? Also multiplying $J^i_{j'}$ with $\delta^{i'}_{j'}$ would probably not crossed my mind so thanks for showing that trick.

Comment: @JoelJärnefelt I'm glad I clarified things. Again, though, you shouldn't talk about is as division; it's equating coefficients.

Comment: By equating coefficinets do you mean that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Something)x_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Something else)x_{i} \Leftrightarrow\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Something) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Something else)$

Comment: @JoelJärnefelt You wouldn't want to keep the $\sum_i$ on either side after the inference.

Comment: Oh that's right. Anyway thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @J.G. Where you say 'it follows by matching $J^i_{i'}$ coefficients that $J_i^{i^\prime}J_{j^\prime}^i=\delta_{j^\prime}^{i^\prime}$. This is not as simple as dividing by $J_{i^\prime}^i$ ...' On the LHS I see the coefficients as $J_j^{i^\prime}J_{j^\prime}^j$ .. is having the $j$ top and bottom of no consequence as it is the 'dummy index'?

Comment: @D-Dᴙum Got it in one.